# Page not found (404) : When try to view a page in django

Tags: django

am new to django , so i wrote a simple program to go to Page2 from Page1 using a link in Page 1 and from Page2 to Page 1 using another link in Page 2, but it is showing Page Not Found .

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from website import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.Index,name='IndexPage'),
    path('darkmode', views.darkmode,name='darkmode'),
]
```

views.py

```
def Index(request):
    return render(request,'Page1.html')

def darkmode(request):
    return render(request,'Page2.html')
```

Page1.html

```
  <div data-url="{% url 'darkmode' %}" class="dark-mode-switcher cursor-pointer shadow-md fixed bottom-0 right-0 box dark:bg-dark-2 border rounded-full w-40 h-12 flex items-center justify-center z-50 mb-10 mr-10">
        <div class="mr-4 text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300">Dark Mode</div>
        <div class="dark-mode-switcher__toggle border"></div>
    </div>
```

Page2.html

```
  <div data-url="{% url 'Index' %}" class="dark-mode-switcher cursor-pointer shadow-md fixed bottom-0 right-0 box dark:bg-dark-2 border rounded-full w-40 h-12 flex items-center justify-center z-50 mb-10 mr-10">
            <div class="mr-4 text-gray-700 dark:text-gray-300">Dark Mode</div>
            <div class="dark-mode-switcher__toggle dark-mode-switcher__toggle--active border"></div>
        </div>
```

and am not able to figure put why this happened , Can anyone help me to figure this out

Comment: Your url '{% url 'Index' %} should be {% url 'IndexPage' %}, because you've set your path name to IndexPage

Comment: it goes to page 2 using darkmode , but even if i use IndexPage also it is not moving from Page2 - Page1 @barbaart